# Cryptographically secure random ASCII-string in PHP

Tags: php, security, random, cryptography

I know about `random_bytes()` in PHP 7, and I want to use it for generating a cryptographically secure (e.g. hard to guess) random string for use as a one-time token or for longer term storage in a cookie.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to convert the output of `random_bytes()` to a string consisting only of human readable characters, so browsers don't get confused. I know about `bin2hex()`, but I'd prefer to use the full ASCII-range instead of hex numbers, for the sake of more bits per length.

Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming your question is merely how to convert bytes to an ASCII representation and not necessarily how to generate a cryptographically secure random string: Have you considered the Base64 encoding and the `base64_encode()` function in PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately Peter O. deleted his answer after receiving negative attention in a review queue, perhaps because he phrased it as a question. I believe it is legitimate answer so I will reprise it.

One easy solution is to encode your random data into the [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) alphabet using `base64_encode()`. This will not produce the "full ASCII-range" as you have requested but it will give you most of it. An even larger ASCII range is output by a suitable base85 encoder, but php does not have a built-in one. You can probably find plenty of open-source base85 encoders for php though. In my opinion the decrease in length of base85 over base64 is unlikely to be worth the extra code you have to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I personally just use a GUID library and concatenate a couple of GUIDs to get a long unique token string. You also have the option to remove the dashes to keep it difficult to know the source and if you want to make it even more complex you can randomly cut back the string by up to 10 char to add complexity to its unknown length.

I use this library for generating my GUIDs

https://packagist.org/packages/ramsey/uuid

```
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;
$token = Uuid::uuid4() . '-' . Uuid::uuid4();
```

Sorry, I overlooked the part about you wanting to use the full scope of 26 alpha char with numeric... Not sure I have an answer for you in this respect but you should have faith in the difficulty of guessing a UUID4, especially when you add a couple together and obfuscate the length by a factor of 10 to make guessing more complex.

Actually, if you could safely generate an array of random numbers in the range of valid ascii char codes then you could convert the entire random array of codes into the respective ascii char and implode them together as a single string.

```
function randomAsciiString($length) {
    return implode('', array_map(
        function($value) {
            return chr($value);
        },
        array_map(
            function($value) {
                return random_int(33, 126);
            },
            array_fill(0, $length - 1, null)
        )
    ));
}
echo randomAsciiString(128);                  // Normal 128 char string
echo randomAsciiString(random_int(118, 128)); // obfuscated length char string for extra complexity.
```

of course though... you should be mindful that you're using all the standard keys on the keyboard and some of those characters are going to upset things that are sensitive ( eg quotes etc.. )

Comment: "...but you should have faith in the difficulty of guessing a UUID4..." No, you should not.

Comment: Why would you not have faith in its ability to generate a random string of char and people having difficulty in guessing?

Comment: We all know that with enough time, processing power and opportunities to poke at something we will eventually guess correctly... so technically nothing is safe in cryptography but if you have a strong chance that something wont be guessed and the apply this to a well designed system that does not allow sometime to poke it until the cows come home then you will be fine in placing faith in UUID4 and more so when you combine a couple of them together to form a uber UUID4

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the letters to be used. For the sake of simplicity I will assume that you intend only big and small English letters to be used. This means that you have 26 big letters and 26 small letters, 52 different possible values. If we view a byte array of n elements as a number of n digits in base 256 and we convert this number into a base 52 number, where A is 0, B is 1, C is 2, ..., a is 26, ..., z is 51, then converting these digits into the corresponding letters will yield the text you wanted.